# Encoding in h264 with ffmpeg on RTX 3080 fails

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, video-conversion

I'm trying to convert a 7200x3600 60fps h265 video using my RTX 3080 to the h264 codec because of some compatibility issue with VR.

This command line result in "`No NVENC capable devices found`" error:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel_device 0 -hwaccel cuda -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_nvenc output.mp4
```

However this command works (for h265):

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel_device 0 -hwaccel cuda -i input.mp4 -c:v hevc_nvenc output.mp4
```

Which for me, means that my gpu is 'NVENC capable' but I don't see what to try.

EDIT:
output of `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i nullsrc -c:v h264_nvenc -gpu list -f null /dev/null`:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200122
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'nullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_nvenc @ 0000017e82c22540] [ GPU #0 - < NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 > has Compute SM 8.6 ]
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Do you have multiple GPUs? What's the output of `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i nullsrc -c:v h264_nvenc -gpu list -f null /dev/null`

Comment: No I have only one gpu, I added the output in my post.

Comment: I had faced a similar issue on my gtx 1050 a long time back, but building ffmpeg from source had resolved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For H.264, nvenc has a max. resolution limit of 4096x4096. Use a software encoder like libx264. But note that a resolution of 7200x3600 is beyond the limit of any valid H.264 level so hope your target player doesn't care. Or use HEVC with different parameters.

Comment: I finally found a good HEVC decoder to play the video.